# bootlean returns true or false how to compare the result?

Tags: android

How can I compare the bootlean to a string? I have tried to change the bootlean to a string output but I can't because of the checkemail function calls for a bootlean.

The check email states that if its a valid email...which returns "true" or "false".

```
 boolean sefsd = checkemails(e.getText().toString());

     if(sefsd.toString().equals("false")){ //do something}
```

Comment: Good to know I wasn't the only one who first thought "boolean" was "boot lean" :) The latter sounds much better anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!sefsd) {
    // sefsd == false
}
```

[Article about if statement.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)
Try to learn Java before Android programming.

Answer (score 1):

If `checkmails` returns type `boolean` then do

```
if (sefsd == false) { /*do something */ }
```